# Java, cannot find getKeyCode()

Tags: java, int, arrow-keys

i did

> import java.awt.event.KeyEvent

but when i type

> KeyEvent.get

the possible suggestions that the IDE give me are

> KeyEvent.getKeyText:

and other methods for char,
what i need to download or import ?

All i want is something that let me read arrow-keys. ty

Comment: If you are referring to `KeyEvent` (the class), you can only access static methods and fields. You need to refer to an instance of `KeyEvent`.

Comment: `getKeyCode()` is not a static method. You cannot access it directly from the class.

Comment: `KeyEvent` is also associated with the AWT GUI framework. If you're doing GUI working (I hope you're using at least Swing), you might be better of with the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `KEY_PRESSED` for static access.

Documentation for reference [here].[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: This does not determine which key was pressed. The OP couldn't use this as an alternative for `getKeyCode()`